# add time interval with value from selected column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am new in Postgres and want to know if there is a better way to solve time interval problem in Postgres.

In MySQL i have:

```
Select STR_TO_DATE(start_time - interval (tkc + tct) second + interval 3 hour, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as start_time 
from table
```

For Postgres I found and wrote query as:

```
select start_time - (interval  '1 second' * (tkc + tct)) + interval  '3 hour' 
from table
```

Comment: The Postgres syntax you suggest above is not what I would use, but I believe it is SQL standard. Given the two example queries you have posted are not the same, it is difficult to suggest improvements or alternatives. You may want to include query output and/or specific information on what you would like to see differently.

Comment: I'm assuming you're aware that the two examples above don't do exactly the same thing (they would give a different result value).  There's several different different ways to express intervals, In postgresql, none of them are significantly better than what you have used.

Comment: I have edited the correct query @Jasen

Comment: There is no other way in Postgres to achieve this. If you want a more compact expression in the select list, you could write a SQL function to do this

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i will look into that. Thanks :) again.

Comment: @SaqibMujtaba If it's simply about the query length: What about: `select start_time + interval  '1 second' * (3 * 3600 - plto - act) 
from table`? It saves one `interval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers. Wonderful to be part of community.

I was able to solve this as below.

```
select start_time - ((tkc + tct)|| ' seconds')::interval + interval '3 hour' as start_time from table
```